# I'm getting a whole new Desktop while remote connecting to windows 10

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

When I open a remote desktop connection to my desktop pc (win 10 enterprise) from a tablet (Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview) the connection succeeds but it seems that my desktop pc is making a entirely new user for this connection.
Because my usual desktop/taskbar icons aren't there, my current opened and used applications aren't open (not even in the taskbar) and I can't access my local user files (I have to put in an account with permissions, after typing my account details it says that I don't have permission). I'm loggin in with the same user account which I always use while working at my desktop pc (btw. there is only one user account on this pc!).

I may get the concept of this whole remote desktop connection wrong, but I thought that I get the exact copy of my desktop at the time I'm loggin in via the remote connection (like using TeamViewer). And in every video I saw it was like that.

Why is it like this?
Is this normal behaviour?
Are there any settings additional to the remote desktop settings I have to change?

Comment: What desktop are you expecting?  The user on the Windows 10 Enterprise machine or the user on the Windows 10 Professional machine?

Comment: @Ramhound The user on the windows 10 enterprise machine.

Comment: Can you log into the user on the physical machine itself?  Have you confirmed you have two user profiles on the machine, you don't actually say, if you confirm if two separate users exist or not.

Comment: Yes I can log into the user on the physical machine. There is only one user profile on the machine (the one I log into with) I've looked and it is a local profile.

Comment: It has to have more then one profile.  Are you looking in the right place to confirm if it does or does not?

Comment: I've been looking at settings -> accounts ... Is this the wrong place?

Comment: `C:\Users` would tell you what users have logged into the machine.

Comment: Ah okay my bad I'm not the full experienced windows user. There are two different user. I'm working in a domain so I got `myUsername` and `myDomain.myUsername`. But this is strange too. Because I'm login with my domain account on both, remote and on the physical machine. Thank you sir, now I've got an idea where I've to start looking. Tomorrow I will look which Profil is active while I'm logged into the physical machine.

Comment: Ok got it. I log into my physical machine with my domain account, but it is somehow treated like a local profil. If I explicitly log in with the local user profil while I'm remote connecting it behave like it should. Thank you again @Ramhound for pointing me in the right direction.